# Show/hide dynamic textbox based on pulldown

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to have jQuery show/hide a dynamically generated textbox based on a pulldown menu selection. My JS skills are extremely limited. I have the following created in a while loop, depending on the number of people:

```
<select name="location[<?=$pid?>]" id="location[<?=$pid?>]">
<option value="<?=$loc_id?>" selected><?=$loc_name?> </option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
<option value="Other">--------</option>
<? $query_loc = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE loc_app = 'Y' ORDER BY loc_name ASC");
while($fetch_loc = mysqli_fetch_array($query_loc)){
     $loc_id = $fetch_loc['loc_id'];
     $loc_name = $fetch_loc['loc_name'];
     ?>
     <option value="<?=$loc_id?>"><?=$loc_name?></option>
     <?
}  ?>
</select>
<input name="location_other[<?=$pid?>]" type="text" id="location_other[<?=$pid?>]" style="display:none" />
```

jQuery function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#location').change(function () { 
        if ($(this).val() == "Other") { 
            $('#location_other').show(); 
        } else { 
            $('#location_other').hide(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

I need to keep the id of the  and the  serialized with the $pid variable for later processing. Is there another way to call the jquery function on these?

The HTML output looks like this:

```
<select name="location[287]" id="location[287]">
        <option value="1" selected>A</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        <option value="Other">--------</option>
        <option value="12">B</option>
        <option value="12">C</option>            
      </select>
      <input name="location_other[287]" type="text" id="location_other[287]" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: please show the output of the php

Comment: can you change the id to `id="location_other<?=$pid?>"`

Comment: no - i need to keep it as an array. Otherwise, when my php script processes it, it loses the info.

Comment: i think name is enough for it, id is not used i think

Comment: @Arun P Johny I stand corrected - looks like that's working. Now how do I get the hide to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#location').change(function () {
        $('input[id^=location_other]').hide();
        if ($(this).val() == "Other") { 
            $('#location_other').show(); 
        } else { 
            $('#location_other' + $(this).val()).hide(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to have any effect. I've been toying with it off and on as I find time but keep getting hung up on what "$('input[id^=location_other]').hide();" is accomplishing. Does it make a difference that I can't predict the array value of location_other?

Comment: whereas this code will display the location_other for the first iteration of my loop, the following Nth loops lose it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="location[287]" id="location[287]">
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<input name="location_other[287]" type="text" id="location_other" style="display:none" />


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
        if ($('select[id^="location"]').val() == "Other") {
            $('#location_other').show();
        } else {
            $('#location_other').hide();
        }

        $('select[id^="location"]').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
                $('#location_other').show();
            } else {
                $('#location_other').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to save my changes in jsfiddle, please try $(document).ready() instead of $(window).load(). http://jsfiddle.net/65NYu/2/

Comment: Getting closer! And thanks for the help. http://jsfiddle.net/65NYu/ Your script will show and hide the same text box with two drop down menus. I need it to show and hide two separate text boxes.

Comment: wrap drop down and text box inside a container and try.http://jsfiddle.net/65NYu/7/